# mvvmcross expandablelistview

Tags: expandablelistview, mvvmcross

I was just wondering if the functionality of or similar to ExpandableListViews was lurking within the Mvvmmcross framework or is this type of control not applicable with multi platform requirements.
The functionality found at
 http://deapsquatter.blogspot.com/2013/02/mvvmcrossdeapextensions.html is cool but not sure if expand/collapse functionality is available.

Any pointers/sample code would be appreciated

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

This is about it (I placed it into Deepsqautter's code). After I tidied up the code, I will place it somewhere handy, or maybe it's a useful addition to mvvmcross itself...

The view:

```
public class BindableExpandableListView : ExpandableListView
    {
        public BindableExpandableListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
            : this(context, attrs, new BindableExpandableListAdapter(context))
        {
        }
    public BindableExpandableListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, BindableExpandableListAdapter adapter)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        var groupTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadAttributeValue(context, attrs,
                                                                           MvxAndroidBindingResource.Instance
                                                                            .ListViewStylableGroupId,
                                                                           AndroidBindingResource.Instance
                                                                           .BindableListGroupItemTemplateId);
 
        var itemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId(context, attrs);
        SetAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.GroupTemplateId = groupTemplateId;
        adapter.ItemTemplateId = itemTemplateId;
    }

    // An expandableListView has ExpandableListAdapter as propertyname, but Adapter still exists but is always null.
    protected BindableExpandableListAdapter ThisAdapter { get { return ExpandableListAdapter as BindableExpandableListAdapter; } }

    

    private IEnumerable _itemsSource;
    [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
    public virtual IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return ThisAdapter.ItemsSource; }
        set { ThisAdapter.ItemsSource = value; }
    }

    public int ItemTemplateId
    {
        get { return ThisAdapter.ItemTemplateId; }
        set { ThisAdapter.ItemTemplateId = value; }
    }

    private ICommand _itemClick;
    public new ICommand ItemClick
    {
        get { return _itemClick; }
        set { _itemClick = value; if (_itemClick != null) EnsureItemClickOverloaded(); }
    }

    public ICommand GroupClick { get; set; }

    private bool _itemClickOverloaded = false;
    private void EnsureItemClickOverloaded()
    {
        if (_itemClickOverloaded)
            return;

        _itemClickOverloaded = true;
        base.ChildClick += (sender, args) => ExecuteCommandOnItem(this.ItemClick, args.GroupPosition, args.ChildPosition);
    }


    protected virtual void ExecuteCommandOnItem(ICommand command, int groupPosition, int position)
    {
        if (command == null)
            return;

        var item = ThisAdapter.GetRawItem(groupPosition, position);
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (!command.CanExecute(item))
            return;

        command.Execute(item);
    }
}
```

and the adapter

```
public class BindableExpandableListAdapter : MvxAdapter, IExpandableListAdapter
    {
    private IList _itemsSource;

    public BindableExpandableListAdapter(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        
    }

    int groupTemplateId;
    public int GroupTemplateId
    {
        get { return groupTemplateId; }
        set
        {
            if (groupTemplateId == value)
                return;
            groupTemplateId = value;

            // since the template has changed then let's force the list to redisplay by firing NotifyDataSetChanged()
            if (ItemsSource != null)
                NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    protected override void SetItemsSource(System.Collections.IEnumerable value)
    {
        Mvx.Trace("Setting itemssource");
        if (_itemsSource == value)
            return;
        var existingObservable = _itemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (existingObservable != null)
            existingObservable.CollectionChanged -= OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;

        _itemsSource = value as IList;

        var newObservable = _itemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (newObservable != null)
            newObservable.CollectionChanged += OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;

        if (value != null)
        {
            // dit weggehaald FlattenAndSetSource(value);
        }
        else
            base.SetItemsSource(null);
    }



    public int GroupCount { get { return (_itemsSource != null ? _itemsSource.Count : 0); } }
    public void OnGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public void OnGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = _itemsSource[groupPosition];
        return base.GetBindableView(convertView, item, GroupTemplateId);
    }

    public long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public long GetCombinedGroupId(long groupId)
    {
        return groupId;
    }

    public long GetCombinedChildId(long groupId, long childId)
    {
        return childId;
    }

    public object GetRawItem(int groupPosition, int position)
    {
        return ((_itemsSource[groupPosition]) as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList()[position];
    }

    public View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var sublist = ((_itemsSource[groupPosition]) as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList();

        var item = sublist[childPosition];
        return base.GetBindableView(convertView, item, ItemTemplateId);
    }

    public int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return ((_itemsSource[groupPosition]) as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList().Count();
    }

    public long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //public object GetRawItem
}
```

And example XAML code:

```
<DeapExtensions.Binding.Droid.Views.BindableExpandableListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/toclist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Chapters; ItemClick ShowCommand"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/indextocsectionlistitem"
    local:GroupItemTemplate="@layout/indextocitem"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

And then even some data example (pseudo code):

```
public class SubItem {
  public String Name {get; set;}
}

// this is the special part: a chapter does not CONTAIN a sublist, but IS a list of subitems.
public class Chapter : List<Subitem> {
  public String Name {get; set;}
}

// en some usage code
var chapters = new List<Chapter>();
var chapter = new Chapter(){Name = "chap 1"};
chapter.Add(new SubItem(){Name = " 1"});
chapter.Add(new SubItem(){Name = "item 2"});
chapters.Add(chap);
```

This is my MvxBindingAttributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxBinding">
    <attr name="MvxBind" format="string"/>
    <attr name="MvxLang" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxControl">
    <attr name="MvxTemplate" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxListView">
    <attr name="MvxItemTemplate" format="string"/>
    <attr name="MvxDropDownItemTemplate" format="string"/>
    <attr name="GroupItemTemplate" format="string"/>

  </declare-styleable>
  <item type="id" name="MvxBindingTagUnique"/>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxImageView">
    <attr name="MvxSource" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

BTW: I have only one project left in MvvmCross, the rest has been converted to Xamarin.Forms or even away from Xamarin. So code is not updated anymore.

Comment: I have added the code to a fork: https://github.com/hlogmans/MvvmCross.DeapExtensions.git

Comment: Hugo, this code still works? I made an upgrade to MvvmCross 3.0.14 and compiled the code. I'm referencing only the dll in my project, but I'm unable to use it. Do you have a sample project on github?

Comment: Yup it works, but I don't have an example project. What is your problem?

Comment: I added a reference to your DLL (DeapExtensions.Binding and DeapExtensions.Binding.Droid). Copied the file BindingAttributes.xml to my Resource folder. Changed the axml file. When compiling I got the error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'GroupItemTemplate' in package 'heysr.app'

Comment: Then you probably have not edited the mvxbindingattributes.xml in your project. At the same level of 'MvxItemTemplate' add an 'GroupItemTemplate' line.

Comment: Yeap! That was the problem. Now I can compile my project but your component is not appearing on screen. Do I need to call some Plugin on initialization?

Comment: Now it works! I created a class 'DeapExtensionsPluginBootstrap' that calls your PluginLoader. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. If you make improvements, please create a pull request so everybody can profit from it.

Comment: @HugoLogmans How to define Chapters to bind with ItemsSource? Can you give a example. Thank you

Comment: chapter must be of IEnumberable<subitem> class. And you provide a list of IEnumerable<Chapter> to ItemsSource.

Comment: I don't quite understand how Chapter and subitem work.  Can you post some code as to how you define these?

Comment: @HugoLogmans, when compiling I got the error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'GroupItemTemplate' in package. I have checked my mvxbindingattributes.xml and i can see entry of GroupItemTemplate.            Here snapshot of "mvxbindingattributes"                                          <declare-styleable name="MvxListView">
    <attr name="MvxItemTemplate" format="string"/>
    <attr name="MvxDropDownItemTemplate" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxExpandableListView">
    <attr name="GroupItemTemplate" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>

Comment: @RaviBhojani see updated answer for my xml. If it still does not work, all code might be outdated. I don't have the time to look at it at the moment, sry.

Comment: In the latest versions you don't need `MvxBindingAttributes` anymore. Also MvvmCross has a buildin `ExpandableListView`. Please open a new topic if you need information on that.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge no-one has done this before

But you can convert an existing Android control into a bound control fairly simply - you've seen exactly how it's done in @deapsquatter's repo.

To convert an ExpandableListView I would take it one step at a time.

1. First get the data in the structure you want to use
2. Then handcraft a non-bound UI - just rapid prototyping
3. Finally take @deapsquatter's sample and try to apply the same principles.

When/if you hit specific issues, then you can always come back here to ask about those issues. But by having 1 and 2 in place first, then you'll have something solid to ask about.

Hope that helps.