# Android ExpandableListView in Xamarin, bindable with MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Has anyone used the Android ExpandableListView control in Xamarin with the MvvmCross framework (binding to collections)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by looking at this: https://github.com/hlogmans/MvvmCross.DeapExtensions.git as shown in this thread:
 [mvvmcross expandablelistview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010246/mvvmcross-expandablelistview)

Comment: Decided to use a flat list with Headers as items in the list. ItemTemplates based on the items content or type will be used to template the items and headers differently.
This works in Android and I believe works very similar in iOS.